# How to declare an integer's value in system.out.println

Tags: eclipse, if-statement

How do I make it so I can plug in the random value of a and b into the system.out.println so it will display in the console window what the random number was?

```
public class MoreIfStmts {

    /* Chase Pittman
    * This program compares two variables and tells which one is greater or if they're equal.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int q=0;
        while (q < 10) {
            q=q+1;
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
                a=(int) (Math.random() * 10);
                b=(int) (Math.random() * 10);
        if (a > b)
        {
            System.out.println ("Blue is better than red.");
        } // This is the end of the then clause.
            else
            {
            if (a < b)
            {
                    System.out.println ("Red is better than blue.");
                } // This is the end of the if clause.

                    else
                    if (a == b)
                    {
                        System.out.println ("Blue is as good as red.");
                } // This is the end of the second else clause.
            } // This is the end of the first else clause.
        } // This is the end of while statement.
    } // This is the end of main.
} // This is the end of class MoreIfStmts.
```

Comment: The comments on all closing braces make your code harder to read, not easier. Eclipse will highlight the corresponding brace for you if you put your cursor on it.

Comment: If you are looking to plug in values externally, you can supply parameters to the 'main' method. This is the purpose of the 'args' parameter.

Answer (score 2):

System.out.println ("Red is better than blue."+ " a="+a+ " b="+b);

Answer (score 0):

You may also use formatted output:

```
System.out.printf("Blue is better than red. a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
```